# How do I count the number of files read into this list?

Tags: r, list, counting

I have a bunch of csv files that I am reading into a list like this:

```
f <- list.files(pattern="201\\d{5}\\.csv")
```

Is there any way to count how many files that I am reading in?

Comment: you should have a look at `?length`. type `length(f)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `length(f)` will give you the number of file names in `f`.